# Erro Unknown Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Ao criar um projeto Maven pelo https://start.spring.io/ e importá-lo no Eclipse IDE, é exibido **1 erro** na view *problems* do eclipse. O problema é que em descrição, não é exibido nenhuma dica(*Unknown*) do que está o ocasionando. Estou seguindo os passos de [um canal do Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpBRFNKg8k4), porém, gostaria de saber se esse erro pode ser impeditivo para mim no desenvolvimento do Projeto, preciso realizar alguma configuração que esteja em falta ou realizar alguma recomendação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente criar o projeto pelo próprio eclipse, sempre vou por ai e nunca tive problemas, new >> project >> spring start project

Comment: Dessa forma, eu perco toda a praticidade de herdar todas as dependencias necessárias para iniciar a implementação, não é?!

Comment: Não perde, tem um wizard onde vc configura as coisas, veja o print https://i.imgur.com/PiAAMCM.png agora que me atentei, estou falando do Spring Tool Suite (STS) mas acho que tem um plugin para o eclipse que habilita essas coisas

Comment: Você está utilizando a instalação embedded do Maven ou possui alguma configuração de proxy em seu `settings.xml`?

Comment: De qualquer forma @AndréFilipe, se o código está compilando ao executar as goals do Maven e está funcionando, você pode selecionar aquele erro e deletá-lo da lista.

Comment: Vou verificar hoje à noite, assim que chegar em casa. **Ok?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz mais algumas pesquisas e consegui simular este problema, de fato é um problema no Eclipse em sí, mais especificamente no `m2e connector`, conforme descreve [este bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340).

Existem duas alternativas:

1. Atualizar o plugin utilizando [este repositório](https://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/1.4/)
2. Reduzir a versão do `maven-jar-plugin.version` em seu `pom.xml`(visualização de pom efetivo) de `3.1.2` para `3.1.1`, conforme este [bug report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16846#issuecomment-492792506)

Comment: Ao adicionar o `<properties> 
  <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>`, foi levantado o seguinte erro em descrição: *Description Resource Path Location Type
Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. Select: Maven->Update Project... from the project context menu or use Quick Fix. line 1 Maven Configuration Problem*.

Comment: Com a atualização de plugin funcionou?

Comment: Vi que era pro Eclipse IDE, estou usando o **S**pring **T**ools **S**uits por isso não baixei o plugin, só alterei o pom.xml

Comment: Legal, caso o Maven Update não tenha funcionado (geralmente um Alt + F5 no projeto, ou botão direito > Maven > Update Project), tente a atualização de plugin também. O STS nada mais é que um Eclipse cheio de plugins, o do maven pode estar desatualizado mesmo assim

Comment: Olá, apenas realizei o **Update Project** em meu projeto e o log de *problems* com o erro foi resolvido.